# c# decryption producing wrong result [Update 1]

Tags: c#, encryption, rijndael

In my program the following happens.

1. A random string is generated and encrypted
   **This is the Encryption Routine:**

   ```
   private static readonly byte[] SALT = new byte[] { 0x26, 0xdc, 0xff, 0x00, 0xad, 0xed, 0x7a, 0xee, 0xc5, 0xfe, 0x07, 0xaf, 0x4d, 0x08, 0x22, 0x3c };
       //TODO: The SALT needs to be derived and unique for each user!

       internal  byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plain)
       {
           string password = Properties.Settings.Default.PasswordOne;
           MemoryStream memoryStream;
           CryptoStream cryptoStream;
           Rijndael rijndael = Rijndael.Create();
           rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
           Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SALT);
           rijndael.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
           rijndael.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
           memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
           cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
           cryptoStream.Write(plain, 0, plain.Length);
           cryptoStream.Close();
           return memoryStream.ToArray();
       }
   ```
2. This encrypted string is saved to a File called DEFT
   **This is the Save Routine:**

   ```
    private void CreateDeft2(FileSystemEncryption fse, string Deft2FileName, string drive)
   {
       if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Creating DEFT2");
       FileStream fs = null;
       StreamWriter sw = null;
       string location = Path.Combine(drive, Deft2FileName);
       try
       {
           fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
           sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.Unicode);

           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Creating Random Contents");
           string fakeContents = CreateRandomString(1024000);      // Create the fake contents
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Converting Random Contents to Bytes");
           byte[] bFakeContents = GetBytes(fakeContents);          // Convert to bytes
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Encrypting Random Content Bytes");
           byte[] ebFakeContents = fse.Encrypt(bFakeContents);     // Encrypt
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Converting Encrypted Bytes to String");
           string sedFakeContents = GetString(ebFakeContents);     // Convert to string

           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Writing DEFT2");
           sw.Write(sedFakeContents);                              // Write it out
           fs.Flush();                                             // Flush the buffer

           sw.Close();
           fs.Close();
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Successfully Created DEFT2");
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Failed to Create DEFT2 " + ex.Message);
           sw.Close();
           fs.Close();
       }
   }
   ```
3. At a particular location within the DEFT file another string of 32 chars is created and saved
   **This is the code for that:**

   ```
   private void InsertDEFT2NameLength(FileSystemEncryption fse, FileStream fs, StreamWriter sw)
       {
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Inserting DEFT2 Name");
           string deft2NameLength = "0";                                       // init the length
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Converting DEFT2 Name to Bytes");
           if (fDEFT2Name.Length < 32)
           {
               for (int idx = fDEFT2Name.Length; idx < 32; idx++)
               {
                   fDEFT2Name = fDEFT2Name + "!";
               }
           }
           byte[] bdeft2Name = GetBytes(fDEFT2Name);                        // convert filename to bytes
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Encrypting DEFT2 Name");
           byte[] ebdeft2Name = fse.Encrypt(bdeft2Name);                       // Encrypt
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Getting Length of Encrypted DEFT2 Name");
           long ebdeft2NameLength = ebdeft2Name.LongLength;                    // Get Length of the Encrypted Bytes as a long
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Converting DEFT2 Name Length to String");
           string sebdeft2NameLength = ebdeft2NameLength.ToString();     // Convert Length to string Add Shebang so we know when we have read the full length
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Converting DEFT2 Name Length to Bytes");
           byte[] bsebdeft2NameLength = GetBytes(sebdeft2NameLength);          // Convert length string to bytes
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Encrypting DEFT2 Name Length");
           byte[] ebsebdeft2NameLength = fse.Encrypt(bsebdeft2NameLength);     // Encrypt
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Converting Encrypted DEFT2 Name Length to String");
           deft2NameLength = GetString(ebsebdeft2NameLength);                  // Convert to string

           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Seeking to Correct Location");
           long startPos = GenerateDEFT2LengthStartPosition();
           fs.Seek(startPos, SeekOrigin.Current);    // Seek to correct location
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("New Position " + startPos.ToString("N0"));
           if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Writing Encrypted Name Length to New Position");
           sw.Write(deft2NameLength);                                          // Write the Encrypted length
           fs.Flush();                                                         // Flush the buffer immediately
       }
   ```

   4. I then try to decrypt that new string. **This decrypts the string (or at least it should!)**

      private long ReadDEFT2Len(string DEFT, long lenPos, FileSystemEncryption fse)
          {
              if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Reading DEFT2 Name Length");
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      ```
          FileStream fs = null;
          StreamReader sr = null;

          try
          {
              fs = new FileStream(DEFT, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
              sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Unicode);

              char[] C = new char[32];
              fs.Seek(lenPos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
              sr.Read(C, 0, 32);

              string sC = new string(C);
              byte[] bsC = GetBytes(sC);

              byte[] dRes = fse.Decrypt(bsC);
              string sbdRes = GetString(dRes);
              foreach (char ic in sbdRes)
              {
                  if (ic == '!') break;
                  sb.Append(ic.ToString());
              }

              sr.Close();
              fs.Close();

              if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("DEFT2 Name Length = " + sb.ToString());
              return long.Parse(sb.ToString());
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("ERROR Reading DEFT2 Name Length " + ex.Message);
              if (sr != null) sr.Close();
              if (fs != null) fs.Close();
              return -1;
          }

      }
      ```

Excuse the formatting - it just won't play nice!

The decryption routine does not decrypt the original string - it simply returns incomprehensible text. **The Decryption routing is here:**

```
internal  byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipher)
    {
        string password = Properties.Settings.Default.PasswordOne;
        MemoryStream memoryStream;
        CryptoStream cryptoStream;
        Rijndael rijndael = Rijndael.Create();
        rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SALT);
        rijndael.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        rijndael.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, rijndael.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(cipher, 0, cipher.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
```

It uses the same salt as the encryptor. The password is the same and the number of bytes read are the same and from the correct location within the file. So, any ideas why this is the case?

**UPDATE 1:**

This code provides me the location where I will Insert into the previously created encrypted DEFT file a new piece of information.

```
private long GenerateDEFT2LengthStartPosition()
        {
            if (DrivesLog != null) DrivesLog("Generating DEFT2 Length Start Position");
            return long.Parse((Properties.Settings.Default.PasswordOne.Length * Properties.Settings.Default.PasswordOne.Length).ToString());
        }
```

As long as I use the same password which it will as it is saved (for testing purposes) it will return the same location to insert the newly encrypted text. In this case it is always 100 returned.

However, in the Hex editor using Decimals for offsets it shows that the newly encrypted text is stored at offset 418.

Why would saving the text like this:

```
long startPos = GenerateDEFT2LengthStartPosition();
            fs.Seek(startPos, SeekOrigin.Current);    // Seek to correct location                
            sw.Write(deft2NameLength);
```

and loading it like this:

```
long lenPos = GenerateDEFT2LengthStartPosition();
 char[] C = new char[32];
                fs.Seek(lenPos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                sr.Read(C, 0, 32);
```

place me in a totally different position within the file?

> So the Question: Why is using the same value 100 to write and read the
>   encrypted text within a file putting the text in a different place to
>   where it is being read from?

Comment: Again, does the encryption-decryption-cycle work on its own, should we look into its code?

Comment: Ok shall check that now - and report back!

Comment: Use `using` statements to make your code cleaner and exception-safe:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yeah it works as a straight switch from plain to encrypted and back - so it must be a logic problem,

Comment: @TimothyShields Yeah, I will do refactoring later - although Usings do not prevent exceptions, they just clean up after you. And I don't think the code is actually any cleaner - just more nested :P

Comment: Take a look at this sample http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/704372/How-to-use-Rijndael-ManagedEncryption-with-Csharp

Comment: @Isalamon. Thanks but the Encryoption Decryption works. The problem is that 1: The insert point is incorrect and 2: It is not inserting the whole cypher only part of it.